# Unable to create a data science project in IBM Watson Studio

Tags: watson-studio

I've been trying to create a data science project on the IBM Watson Studio but keep getting the error (An error occurred. You can only have one instance of a Lite plan per service. To create a new instance, either delete your existing Lite plan instance or select a paid plan.) on my window screen.

Comment: As the error says, you are trying to create a service/resource that already exists in your account. Lite services are limited in how many you can create. Try linking to the existing one.

Comment: With a lite account you are also locked to the region where you created your first service/resource.

Answer (score 0):

To echo Simon's comment for similar concerns, linking to an existing service that exists in your account should overcome the issue you're encountering.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using a basic plan where you can create only 1 instance at a time. You first have to search for your existing instance. You have to delete that instance and then you can create a new one.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34623943)